# How to not send an error message when a cancel button is pressed in 'simpledialog.askstring' window?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

So I am currently trying to make a program that allows me to enter a string which outputs to a text window in tkinter. However, I am getting an error message when the 'cancel' button is pressed in the simpledialog.askstring window.

this is the error message that I am getting in the Python Shell:

```
_tkinter.TclError: wrong # args: should be ".!text insert index chars ?tagList chars tagList ...?"
```

I just wanted the program to do nothing when the cancel button is pressed. :(

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import simpledialog
import tkinter.messagebox

class Thing:
    def __init__(self):
        global buttonThing
        global window
        window = Tk()

        frame1 = Frame(window)
        frame1.pack()
        buttonThing = Button(frame1, text = "click me", command = self.clickMe)
        buttonThing.pack()
        self.text =Text(window)
        self.text.pack()
        window.mainloop()


    def clickMe(self):
        uwu = simpledialog.askstring("hey","put stuff")

        self.text.insert(END, uwu)



Thing()
```

Answer (score 3):

your dialogbox returned None when you press cancel and the error exist when you tried to insert None in text control

so replace this code `self.text.insert(END, uwu)` with this

```
if uwu: 
    self.text.insert(END, uwu)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could always run it in a `try: except:` block, like so:

```
def clickMe(self):
    try:
        uwu = simpledialog.askstring("hey","put stuff")
        self.text.insert(END, uwu)

    except Exception:
        pass
```

But the proper way would be to do what @Mahmoud Elshahat replied